# Как заменить управление WASD на управление с помощью джойстика

Tags: c#, unity3d

Хочу сделать джойстик для управления персонажем в 3д игре для телефонов, уже нашел ассет джойстика, и скрипт передвижения персонажа тоже есть, но можно ли сделать так что бы просто задать джойстику клавиатурные клавиши (например если переместить стик влево, то нажмется A). Если так возможно сделать то пожалуйста подскажите как, а то не охото в скрипт игрока лезть так как пока плохо разбираюсь в c#

Comment: Если вы реагируете на `Input.GetKeyDown()`, можно точно также реагировать на джойстик. Просто вынесите ваши [`KeyCode`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/KeyCode.html) в настройки. Правда в документации пишут: For joystick and gamepad button presses, consider using [`Input.GetButtonDown`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetButtonDown.html) and [`Input.GetButtonUp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetButtonUp.html) instead of the `KeyCode`

Comment: `Input.GetAxis("Vertical")` и `Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")` будет работать и с джойстиком и клавиатурой